# Search API with views -> Apply filters

Tags: views, search

I have a website where i manage to create a database, display it with the views module and add a Search box with Search API. 
I followed this tutorial: http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-create-search-pages-using-views-drupal-7

I'm using a bundle filter in my Index. My page only shows and search content from a specific content type.
On that content type i have a field "category" with 2 radio options.

What i want to do is be able to filter the search by that category: If i choose option A, when i type my search it will only search the content within that category.

It must be really easy but i just can't figure it out. You guys have any ideas?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an exposed filter to the view for the category field. Under the advanced settings in views you can select to display filters as a block so that you can place it above the search block.