# Search API display message when match not found

Tags: views

I had an issue before ([Search API with views -> Apply filters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123120/search-api-with-views-apply-filters)) that has been solved already.

I have a website where i manage to create a database, display it with the views module and add a Search box with Search API.

The search module works great but i would like to know how can I make it to display a message when there's no match found. Something like "Your search didn't match any documents. Please try again."

Does anyone know how do I do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: hmmm... have you tried or considered a custom tpl file if the UI isn't functioning like it should?

Comment: I made a copy of search-result.tpl.php to the root of my template with the following code: <div class="<?php print $classes;?>">
  <?php if ($result_count) : ?>
    <?php print render($search_performance); ?>
    <?php print render($spellcheck); ?>
    <h2><?php print t('Search results');?></h2>
    <ol class="search-results">
      <?php print render($search_results); ?>
    </ol>
    <?php print render($pager); ?>
  <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php print t('Your search yielded no results.');?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div> 
But nothing seems to work.

Comment: search-result.tpl.php is called for each search result of the core search module. You are bypassing that module by using search API and Views. You need to create a custom views tpl (https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/group/views_templates/7)

Answer (score 0):

In Views, under the Advanced Tab, click on NO RESULTS BEHAVIOUR. There you can include a general statement (global text) when it returns nothing.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work... I wonder if there's another way... Thank you!